# Content of the Local namespace in Python

Tags: python, namespaces

I read in [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=namespaces#:%7E:text=The%20local%20namespace%20for%20a%20function%20is%20created%20when%20the%20function%20is%20called:%7E:text=The%20local%20namespace%20for%20a%20function%20is%20created%20when%20the%20function%20is%20called) of the Python documentation that the local namespace for a function is created when the function is called.

In the example code below, I use function `locals()` to get the local namespace (a dictionary) of function `g()`. To my surprise, the dictionary this function returns, includes identifier `f_var`, which appears in the body of function `g()` only after I call function `locals()`.

```py
# local_namespace_test.py
def f():

    f_var = 55

    def g():
        g_var = 3
        print(f"locals in g(): {locals()}")
        print(f_var)
        return

    g()
    return

f()
```

Why the local namespace of function `g()` includes the name `f_var` in this situation?
Why if I remove the line `print(f_var)`, then `f_var` is not in the dictionary returned by `locals()`?

Output of running the above code:

```bash
$ python3 local_namespace_test.py 
locals in g(): {'g_var': 3, 'f_var': 55}
55
```

Output of running the above code with line `print(f_var)` commented:

```bash
$ python3 local_namespace_test.py 
locals in g(): {'g_var': 3}
```

Comment: I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXugs4B3lwU&t=26s) by mCoding really helpful in understanding variable scopes.

Comment: This is related to Python's somewhat unusual scoping rules.  Python needs to prescan your function to figure out whether the variables you're using are global, local, or nonlocal.  It remembers that so it can watch for "used before set" errors.

Answer (score 0):

Python will look from inside out for the variables. In that case you have a "chained" call stack `global -> f() -> g()`.

So in `g()` there are two variables referenced: `g_var` and `f_var`. `g_var` is also defined in `g()` so `g_var` is a local variable and thus in the inner namespace of `g()`.

`f_var` is referenced in `g()` by the `print` statement, but not defined there. So Python will look, if a different namespace contains a reference to `f_var` and goes up the "stack". The function `f()` contains a definition of `f_var` and so the `f_var` namespace entry in `f()` is copied to `g()`.

In case there is no reference to `f_var` in `g()` (i.e. leaving out the print statement), `f_var` will not be copied to the inner namespace, as it is not needed in `g()`.

In case the `f()` function does not contain a definition of `f_var`, Python will look one step "further up", i.e. in the global namespace, if `f_var` is defined. So in this case:

```
f_var=44
def f():
    def g():
        g_var = 3
        print(f"locals in g(): {locals()}")
        print(f"globals in g(): {globals()}")
        print(f_var)
        return
    g()
    return
f()
```

will return

```
locals in g(): {'g_var': 3}
globals in g(): {'__name__': '__main__', [...] 'f_var': 44, 'f': <function f at 0x7f9286480e18>}
44
```

The return value will be the global `f_var`, which is not in the local namespace, but in the global one.

Comment: understood. However, your answer leads me to think that Python will set the local namespace of a function even before the function body is executed for the first time. According to your answer, it seems Python will peruse the function body prior to execution, and if there is some reference that can only be found in an enclosing scope, it will be copied from that enclosed scope to the local scope of the function. I have not found such kind behavior anywhere I have read about Python scopes. Could you give me some references to read about this online?